# Android alpha animation: override initial alpha value

Tags: android, android-animation

Basically I want something to fade-in and then fade-out. Initially it should be invisible, and when the animation is ended, it should also be invisible.

```
targetView.alpha = 0f;

    var aa = AlphaAnimation(0f, 1.0f);
    aa.duration=2000;
    aa.repeatMode = Animation.REVERSE;
    aa.repeatCount = 1;
```

I have tried the code above, but it did not work. it seems that the alpha animation is multiplying the initial alpha with that animation. So, 0f * 1.0f = 0f = invisible.

After searching for an answer, I have tried this, but it did not work.

```
    aa.fillBefore= true;
    aa.fillAfter=true;
```

How can I make the animation ignore the initial alpha value? Is it impossible, and I should change the visibility at the start/end of the animation manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are right about "it seems that the alpha animation is multiplying the initial alpha with that animation. So, 0f * 1.0f = 0f = invisible.".

Just don't use `targetView.alpha = 0f;`, use `targetView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` instead.